How can I view all the uploaded files associated with an Azure OpenAI assistant in Python?
I’m using Python to benchmark questions from documents and have instantiated my assistant in a jupyter notebook. I’d like to confirm the assistant has the files I uploaded to it but can’t seem to find documentation on what function would be used for this. Using latest version of Python API for Azure OpenAI.

You can use below code to retrieve details about your assistant and number file you uploaded.
from openai import AzureOpenAI
    
client = AzureOpenAI(
    api_key="<key>",  
    api_version="2024-05-01-preview",
    azure_endpoint = "<endpoint>"
    )

my_assistant  =  client.beta.assistants.retrieve("assistantid")

print(my_assistant.name)
print(my_assistant.tool_resources)

Output:
tst 
{'code_interpreter': {'file_ids': ['assistant-5l0sZhHcEqQablxIbxQvnz60', 'assistant-YxpChfW2XL8Dt12s9zVha2IU']}}

Here you will get the file you have attached to your assistant.
Whatever the tool you have using and it resources are fetched.
Also, learn more about the assistants api here
If you wish to see all files attached to all the assistants, then use below.
my_assistants = client.beta.assistants.list(
    order="desc",
    limit="20",
)
for i in my_assistants.data:
    print(i.name)
    print(i.tool_resources)

